# text processing: how to filtering type of word only noun

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
flat_list = ['speed','glass','front','fond','bezel','design','pleasure','view','day','inky']
```

I have a coding like this :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

for w in flat_list:
    syns = wordnet.synsets(w)
    print(w, syns[0].lexname().split('.')[0]) if syns else (w, None)
```

and the output:

```
speed noun
glass noun
front noun
fond adj
bezel noun
design noun
pleasure noun
view noun
day noun
inky adj
```

how to delete/remove a type of words other than noun?

Thankyou

Comment: Please edit your tags.

Comment: where is the flat_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, since your code is incomplete I'll assume you can get get a similar list sent

```
sent = [["speed", "noun"],["glass", "noun"],["front", "noun"],["fond", "adj"],["bezel", 
         "noun"],["design", "noun"],["inky", "adj"]]
for i in sent:
    if i[1] == "noun":
         print(i[0])
```